# Sympy not solving convolution integral

Tags: sympy, convolution, integral

I'm trying to solve some convolution integrals but without any luck.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

t1 = 0.01
t1_sym = sp.Symbol('t_1')
F0 = 30e3
F0_sym = sp.Symbol('F_0')
m = 4000
m_sym = sp.Symbol('m')
k = 5000e3
k_sym = sp.Symbol('k')
omega0_sym = sp.sqrt(k_sym/m_sym)
t = sp.Symbol('t')
tau = sp.Symbol(r'\tau')

F1_sym= 2*F0_sym*tau/t1_sym


x1_sym =  sp.integrate((F1_sym*sp.sin(omega0_sym*(t-tau))/(omega0_sym*m_sym)) ,(tau,0,t))
```

I would be really grateful for any insights.

Answer (score 3):

In general, it is a good practise to provide sympy any information available about the parameters and variables involved in an integral, instead of simply declaring them as `symbols`. From the numerical values you are using, it is clear that all variables and parameters are real and positive. You can provide sympy this information when you define them. With this information, sympy provides an expression for the integral (I will leave it to you to check if it is correct or not)

```
t1_sym = sp.Symbol('t_1', positive = True)
F0_sym = sp.Symbol('F_0', positive = True)
m_sym = sp.Symbol('m', positive = True)
k_sym = sp.Symbol('k', positive = True)
omega0_sym = sp.sqrt(k_sym/m_sym)
t = sp.Symbol('t', positive = True)
tau = sp.Symbol(r'\tau', positive = True)

F1_sym= 2*F0_sym*tau/t1_sym
x1_sym =  sp.integrate((F1_sym*sp.sin(omega0_sym*(t-tau))/(omega0_sym*m_sym)) ,(tau,0,t))
print(x1_sym)
```

> `2*F_0*t/(k*t_1) - 2*F_0*sqrt(m)*sin(sqrt(k)*t/sqrt(m))/(k**(3/2)*t_1)`

Comment: Right, the key point being that the assumptions ensure `omega0_sym` is real.